# Does it make any sense to make struct immutable?

Tags: c, struct, constants

Since I came to C from higher level Java where we don't have type quialifiers like `const` in order to make a type immutable we have to declare all its members final and be sure the members are immutable by themselves.

By contract, in C we have type quialifier `const`.

To be more specific, let me provide an example I'm currently stuck with. I have the following

`application.h`:

```
struct application_config_t{
    int poll_interval;
    int compression_ratio;
    //other config parameters
};

struct application_t{  //This structure make me confused
    void (*run_application)(struct application_t*);
    void (*stop_application)(struct application_t*);
};

struct application_t* create_app(const struct application_config_t);
void release_app(struct application_t*);
```

I'm not sure about how to define `application_t` structure. Its only purpose is to do the actaul run with `run_application` and to handle `SIGINT` with `stop_application` to perform graceful shutdown and then after `stop_application` returns to call `release_app(struct application_t*)` to free the memory.

I have the following case to choose:

***I***. Immutable `application_t`

```
struct application_t{
    void (*const run_application)(struct application_t*);
    void (*const stop_application)(struct application_t*);
}
```

I think this is fine because once created an application should not be modified. But creation of such an immutable structure will entail `memcpy` call anyway...

***II***. Mutable `application_t` while create application will be declared as

```
const struct application_t* create_app(const struct application_config_t);
```

This would be fine, but I want to release the memory pointed to by `struct application_t*` after `stop_application` returns. Releasing `struct application_t*` means that `appliaction_t` is not really `const`. And usage like

```
struct application_config_t cfg;
//...
const struct application_t *app_ptr = create_app(cfg);
(app_ptr -> run_application)(app_ptr);
release_app((struct application_t *) app_ptr); //const cast
```

would require cast against `const`ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Releasing struct application_t* means that appliaction is not really const

Actually it is. The client code could not mutate it, and should not be using it further after handing it over to `release_app` anyway. It is `const` throughout its lifetime, and if `release_app` accepts by a pointer to const, it will be semantically correct (just do the cast inside `release_app`).

Why do I say it will be semantically correct? Because when `create_app` allocates space for the structure and initializes it, it isn't `const` in there, is it? The `const` is added later as part of a contract. So accepting a const pointer in `release_app` is just following the same contract you already established. The fact the API pair knows the storage can be mutated doesn't break the contract.

Comment: _Because when create_app allocates space for the structure and initializes it, it isn't const in there, is it?_ I have a question. If we declare `const struct application_t* create_app(const struct application_config_t);` and `void release_app(const struct application_t*);` we would require the following contract: "Once application is created it cannot be modified till it is released" Does it make any sense? In here `create_app` returns `const` preventing it from any modification as soon it is created.

Comment: @SomeName - That's the contract you wanted. At least that's how I read your question. So yeah, it makes sense to codify it in the types involved. I'd even go a step further and say it doesn't make sense to do it otherwise. If you return a `const application_t *` only, how could user code ever obtain a pointer to a non-const version, unless by breaking the contract somehow?